# A problem from Neukirch's algebraic number theory book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The problem is : Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an integral ideal of $K$ and $\mathfrak{a}^m = (\alpha)$ where $K$ is a finite extension of $Q$ . Show that $\mathfrak{a}$ becomes a principal ideal in the field $L = K(\sqrt[m]\alpha)$ in the sense that $\mathfrak{a}O_L = (\beta)$ for some $\beta \in O_L$.

My attempt :

Claim : $\mathfrak{a}O_L = (\sqrt[m]\alpha)$.

Let $x \in  \mathfrak{a}O_L$ . Then $x = \sum a_ix_i $ where $a_i \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $x_i \in O_L$. Since $$\{1, \sqrt[m]\alpha, (\sqrt[m]\alpha)^2,\dots,(\sqrt[m]a)^{m-1}\} $$ is a basis, each $a_i$ can be written as linear combination of the basis elements where co-efficients coming from $O_L$.Clearly $x \in \sqrt[m]\alpha$. to show the other inclusion , its enough to show that $\sqrt[m]\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}O_L$.

But I can not show it. Any hints will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim is correct. Here is a relatively short proof:
Clearly $(\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_L)^m = \alpha \mathcal{O}_L = (\sqrt[m]{\alpha}\mathcal{O}_L)^m$. 
Now every ideal in $\mathcal{O}_L$ decomposes uniquely into a product of prime ideals, so we can write (uniquely) $\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_L=\prod_{i=1}^s \mathfrak{p}_i^{k_i}$ for distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ and $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. But then $(\sqrt[m]{\alpha}\mathcal{O}_L)^m = (\mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_L)^m = \prod_{i=1}^s \mathfrak{p}_i^{mk_i}$, whence
$\sqrt[m]{\alpha}\mathcal{O}_L = \prod_{i=1}^s \mathfrak{p}_i^{mk_i / m} = \mathfrak{a}\mathcal{O}_L$ which was our original claim.